# Error `create` on resource 'template[/etc/awslogs//cwlogs.cfg]'

Tags: chef-infra, amazon-cloudwatch, cookbook, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to do a chef run but keep receiving the error in the title. The log output is as follows;

```
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/tmp/cwlogs.cfg]'
================================================================================

Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
------------------------------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/runs/b2cd9efb-b9d2-4c1a-b582-5ebfbe933bdd/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/phpapp/recipes/setup.rb

45: template "/tmp/cwlogs.cfg" do
46:   source "cwlogs.cfg.erb"
47:   owner "root"
48:   group "root"
49:   mode 0644
50: end
51: # cloudwatch packages

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/runs/b2cd9efb-b9d2-4c1a-b582-5ebfbe933bdd/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/phpapp/recipes/setup.rb:45:in `from_file'

template("/tmp/cwlogs.cfg") do
action [:create]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
default_guard_interpreter :default
source "cwlogs.cfg.erb"
declared_type :template
cookbook_name "phpapp"
recipe_name "setup"
mode 420
owner "root"
group "root"
path "/tmp/cwlogs.cfg"
end

Template Context:
-----------------
on line #30
28: #
29: 
30: [<%= node[:opsworks][:stack][:name] %>]
31: datetime_format = [%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]
32: log_group_name = <%= node[:opsworks][:stack][:name].gsub(' ','_') %>
```

I have tried looking over the existing answers to similar questions but they've all identified different problems that don't seem to reflect what is happening in my case.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your template has an embedded code which causes this...
from looking at your snippets, what is the value of `node[:opsworks][:stack][:name]`?

Comment: my stack name is "sambi-test"

Comment: @hamdiHasnaoui: make sure the value you mentioned is indeed assigned to the variable, since from here like it is null